# Ember.js: Calculate one object's properties in an array using multiple object in an array controller

Tags: ember.js

Though i've had some success learning Ember and how to use it within the context I require, I'm struggling to find a solution to this requirement.

I am using Ember to process an array of field definitions so that I can dynamically generate a form of fields to present to the user. Some of these fields are calculated based on the other fields in the collection - so when generating the fields the view element needs to be able to get the value of one or more of the other fields. I've tried putting a calculated control in the field object, and also in the array controller using propert(@each) but nothing has worked. I've tried too many different permeatations to show my attempted solution here, so I have cleaned the code and left it ready to add the bound functionality required.

I've probably made it harder for myself by using a FieldController but it works so beautifully in using one view_field template to generate a form of view_fields.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ember.js: Calculate properties using multiple object in an array controller</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-0.9.5.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    //the application
    App = Ember.Application.create({

    });
    //the model

     App.Field = Ember.Object.extend({
        "name": null,
        "value": null, 
        "controlsource": null
    });
    //an array controller to interface between the data and the views
    App.FieldController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        content: [],

    }); 
    App.instanceFieldController=App.FieldController.create();

    //populate the controller with data
    App.instanceFieldController.pushObjects([   
        App.Field.create({name:"field1",value:"1",controlsource:""}),
        App.Field.create({name:"field2",value:"2",controlsource:""}),
        App.Field.create({name:"field3",value:null,controlsource:"field1"}),//this field's value should be calculated from field1
        App.Field.create({name:"field4",value:null,controlsource:"field2"})//this field's value should be calculated from field2
    ]);

    //A collection-view which has a collection of a view, each of which defines the presentation of a fields
    App.FieldCollectionView = Em.CollectionView.extend({            
        itemViewClass: Em.View.extend({
            templateName: "textFieldTemplate"       
        }),
        contentBinding: "App.instanceFieldController.content"
    });

</script>
```

```
<h1>Ember.js: Calculate properties using multiple object in an array controller</h1>

<!-- THE FORM TO BE POPULATED WITH THE FIELDS -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <form action="">
        {{view App.FieldCollectionView}}
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
</script>
<!-- THE TEMPLATE FOR HOW TO DISPLAY EACH FIELD -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="textFieldTemplate">
    <label {{bindAttr for="textField.elementId"}}>{{content.name}}</label>              
    {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="content.value"}}      
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what values you want out of this? I'm not getting a real good sense of the desired outcome, here. Also, it's a bad idea to set objects as values in `extend` as they get shared by any instances, as objects are passed by reference and the reference resides on the prototype. An `ArrayController` will get an array for its `content` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. The aim is to create a form dynamically, without knowing which fields prior to execution. Reason: the fields and the exact configuration of them can be changed by the user (and stored in a db). The db will tell Ember the name(N) of the field, its value(V) or its calculated value(C). E.g. N='Firstname',V='Joe'; N='Lastname', V='Blogs'; N='Fullname', **C="Firstname + ' ' + Lastname"**. So the ArrayController will contain 3 elements, the third requiring binding (custom function with an eval statement) to the other two but all three displayed within a CollectionView.